# Formatting HDD containing VHD

Tags: hard-drive, format, vhd

I want to format my hard drive however I lack a second or sufficient external storage to backup my important files.  Is it possible to create a VHD and then format the physical hard drive without deleting the files in the VHD?

Comment: You can choose to format specific partitions. Make a new partition (B), copy your files there, then format the original/unwanted partition (A)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have enough free space left in your disk for the backup, you can partition your disk to create another volume and move your important files there. You can format the main partition by itself after this.

In Windows 7, You can use the disk management tool (Control Panel > Administrative Tools) to do this.

Answer (score 1):

No, unless you put the VHD on a secondary partition. But if you have the second partition, you wouldn't need a VHD.

Yes, you can create another partition supposing you have the space however:

1. You will likely need to shrink your current partition first.
2. If a system partition, you will not be able to shrink while booted into the OS.
3. Formatting the wrong partition will cause data loss so you have to be careful.
4. If the data is important to you, you should have a backup anyway.

A nice tool to do this job is the [GPARTED](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) live CD. Works with most file systems including Windows' NTFS.